# How to create PDF/UA in iText7 with text hyperlink

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, itext7, accessible

I am trying to create a PDF/UA compliant file that contains a text hyperlink with iText 7. Both the Acrobat Preflight test for PDF/UA and the PDF Accessibility Checker (PAC 3) complain that the PDF file say that the PDF is not compliant.

PAC 3 says ""Link" annotation is not nested inside a "Link" structure element" and the Acrobat Preflight test says the Link annotation does not have an alternate description in the Contents key.
The following is my attempt to create PDF/UA compliant output that contains a text hyperlink.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public void testHyperLink() throws IOException {
    // Create PDF/UA with text hyperlink
    String filename = "./results/HyperLink.pdf";
    WriterProperties properties = new WriterProperties();
    properties.addUAXmpMetadata().setPdfVersion(PdfVersion.PDF_1_7);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(filename, properties);
    pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    //Make document tagged
    pdfDoc.setTagged();
    pdfDoc.getCatalog().setLang(new PdfString("en-US"));
    pdfDoc.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setDisplayDocTitle(true));
    PdfDocumentInfo info = pdfDoc.getDocumentInfo();
    info.setTitle("Hello Hyperlinks!");
    document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    // Must embed font for PDF/UA
    byte[] inputBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./resources/fonts/opensans-regular.ttf"));
    boolean embedded = true;
    boolean cached = false;
    PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(inputBytes, PdfEncodings.CP1252, embedded, cached);
  
    Text text = new Text("This is a Text link");
    text.setFont(font);
    text.setFontSize(16F);
    // Add alternate text for hyperlink
    text.getAccessibilityProperties().setAlternateDescription("Click here to go to the iText website");
    PdfAction act = PdfAction.createURI("https://itextpdf.com/");
    text.setAction(act);

    Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
    para.add(text);
    document.add(para);
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Created "+ filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Link object might be what you want:

```
            Link lnk = new Link("This is a Text link",
                PdfAction.CreateURI("https://itextpdf.com/"));
            lnk.SetFont(font);
            lnk.GetLinkAnnotation().SetBorder(new PdfAnnotationBorder(0, 0, 0));//Remove the default border
            lnk.GetAccessibilityProperties().SetAlternateDescription("Click here to go to the iText website");
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            para.Add(lnk);
            document.Add(para);
```